# Newly created ubuntu and i am not a part of sudoers file

Tags: 20.04, sudo, configure

I am using virtualbox to create use ubuntu. I have small experience in creating unix systems. However i just crashed my latest ubuntu so i created a new one. I am currently trying to configure the 22.04.3 version of ubuntu. When i start it up i am not a part of the sudoers file and cannot really do anything. I feel lost and don't know how to fix it. Previously when i configured my ubuntus i got to a "install" page inside ubuntu desktop which also enabled me to create a sudo user/owner but im not getting that page anymore.

edit:
I have been following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5MhydijWmc&t=664s. The linked timestamp also displays the install page im referring to which  i never gain access to.

Comment: I edited more information regarding my situation. I never get the chance to actually create an admin. It just straight up starts to download files and then reboots, never allowing me to input anything.

Comment: The installer only appears if you are booting the installer .iso (9:17-10:25 on the video). Are you booting *the installer* or are you booting into *an already installed system*?